# Create model on a chronological dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, regression

I use the R language, and I would like to carry out a feature selection on time series data.  The date information is contained in a year field. I'm using the *lm()* function to test what it does, but I'd like to know if I'm doing it correctly. My goal is to train on the data except for the last line and to predict the target for the last line.

```
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004)
target <- runif(5)
colonne3 <- sample(1:100, 5, replace = TRUE)
colonne4 <- sample(1:100, 5, replace = TRUE)     
tsd <- data.frame(Date = year, target = target, Colonne3 = colonne3, Colonne4 = colonne4)
# create train, test data
train <- data[1:4, ]; test <- data[5, -2]
# loop for each combinations of variables (without the year column and target)
    formula <- as.formula(paste("target", " ~ year + ", paste(combination, collapse = " + ")))
    model <- lm(formula, train) 
    pred <- model %>% predict(test)
...
```

I'd like to know if we specify in the formula that the year must always be present, does the model consider that it's a chronological dataset ?
That each value in a line depends on the date, in my case I can replace the year values with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 values